# UIButton Not Going to Target

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, ios13

I have a UICollectionViewController being used as my main VC and then a UICollectionViewCell set to the top as a header. But when I try and press the button inside the cell I am unable to get a response.  I am using the initWithFrame for my viewDidLoad.  This is the case for all the buttons on this cell. Any thoughts?

Code from the UICollectionViewCell or header

```
let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle("Loading", for: .normal)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.isEnabled = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()

    @objc func handleButtonFunction() {
            print("button clicked")
        }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            addSubview(editProfileFollowButton)
            editProfileFollowButton.anchor(top: postLabel.bottomAnchor, left: postLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 30)


        }
```

Comment: By any chance, did you disable cell selection (`allowsSelection = no`)?

Comment: @MAT  - no I didn't add any disable lines to the cell or CollectionView.

Comment: Are you getting button tap effect(pressed down)?

Comment: @Kamran yes, it flickers like I have clicked it but I do not get the print statement from the target.

Comment: @ShawnaBoucher Seems very strange. Atleast it should print the `button clicked` statement. I would suggest share the complete file or a sample example with the issue somewhere on github.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you can try. First, try `cell.bringSubviewToFront(cell.button)`. If that doesn't work, try `cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.

Comment: I added both lines to the CollectionView ( this function: override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { ) but neither worked.  For the cell.bringSubViewToFront - where you have cell.button there I put the cell view. Not sure if that was correct.

Comment: Try `cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath:`